# Creating malloc() buffer overrun in C

Tags: c, malloc

I want to write a check unit test for malloc(3) using the "check library".

This unit test is supposed to produce buffer overruns.

1. Is allocating a double on an int variable (i.e int *ptr = malloc(3)) a buffer overrun?
2. What about allocating a bigger number than the maximum value of an int?

Could you please give me other simple examples for buffer overruns?

Comment: There is a maximum value of a number right? So I cannot write digits indefinitely on an int value.

Comment: As I said, my test case is supposed to create a buffer overrun. Can I do that if the int pointer that I am allocating (int *ptr = malloc (3)) I give it a big value (i.e *ptr = 59595959595959595959595959595)? So is this a buffer overrun?

Comment: It is a buffer overrun if `sizeof(int) > 3` on your platform. Otherwise, no.

Answer (score 4):

To overrun a buffer, you need to access a buffer outside its guaranteed size or before its beginning. Allocation doesn't really access any visible buffers, so it's hard to see how any kind of allocation would be a buffer overrun unless there was a bug in the allocation routine itself or its structures were corrupted.

> Is allocating a double on an int variable (i.e int *ptr = malloc(3)) a buffer overrun?

No, since no buffer is being accessed.

> What about allocating a bigger number than the maximum value of an int?

No, since no buffer is being accessed.

To overrun a buffer, you must first have a buffer and then overrun it. For example:

```
int* j = malloc (2 * sizeof (int));
j[2] = 1;
```

Here I allocate a buffer with space for two integers and then overrun it by accessing the third integer (0 is the first, 1 is the second, so 2 is the third).

Comment: And also `int i = j[2];` would be a buffer overrun, albeit a read instead of a write operation.  It would also be accessing uninitialized data, as would `i = j[0];` or `i = j[1];` which are not buffer overruns and are otherwise OK.

Answer (score 2):

Writing or reading past the end of a buffer allocated by `malloc` produces [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which means you can't depend on any particular behavior when it happens.  The program may appear to work, it may core dump, or it may output unexpected results.

Because overrunning a malloc'ed buffer caused undefined behavior, creating test cases for it is pointless unless you're testing a particular implementation of `malloc`.  Based on the wording of your question, that does not seem to be the case.